# 2021 Salsa Fargo and GRX 2x11 components

Tags: bottom-bracket, compatibility, gravel, grx

I’d like your advice on GRX component with 2021 Salsa Fargo frameset.
I didn’t research enough prior to purchase, and I found out that Bottom Bracket size was wrong, and even more, GRX may not work after all?

- Frame : 2021 Salsa Fargo (comes with BSA 73 BB)
- Shifters : Shimano GRX 810 (both right and left) 2x11
- Brake : Shimano BR RS785 (due to flat mount)
- Front derailleur : GRX 810
- Rear derailleur : GRX 812 (11 speed, 42T max)

I bought a GRX groupset which came with RX600-11 (46-30T) Crankset, and Shimano RS500 BSA 68/73 bottom bracket.
But BB shell was too short and didn’t fit.

Can I purchase any other Bottom Bracket and Crankset like Race Face and keep rest of GRX component?  Or do you suggest to re-purchase other entire groupset?

My goal is to use drop handlebars.  I don’t have any preference on Shimano or SRAM components as long as they work.

---

Update:  I decided to take your advice and change my plan to 1x system and Goat Link. Sounds like I can then use Sunrace 11-50 cassette.

My last question will be compatibility of mountain crankset.  It seems many folks use Race Face Turbine with race face chain ring. Will it work with GRX rear derailleur?

About the bottom bracket, I’m thinking Cane Creek Hellbender 70, or Chris King Threadfit 30.

I forgot to mention about wheels I got. So, this is the list of what I got.

- Frame : 2021 Salsa Fargo (comes with BSA 73 BB)
- Handlebar : Cowchipper
- Shifters : Shimano GRX 810 (both right and left) 1x11
- Brake : Shimano BR RS785 (due to post & IS mount)
- Front derailleur : none
- Rear derailleur : GRX 812 + WT Goat Link
- Cassette : Sunrace 11-50
- Wheelset : 27.5 DT Swiss XM551 30mm 350hub (Boost)

New plan - Bottom Bracket :

- Cane Creek Hellbender 70 or Chris king Threadfit 30
- Crank : Race Face Turbine 136mm spindle
- Chainring : Race Face Cinch Direct Mount Oval 32T

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to run a GRX or other Shimano road/gravel crank on a 73mm shell like the Fargo has. The spindle isn't long enough and there's no bottom bracket that can solve that problem.

I don't believe that the GRX FD you have will be able to get to the outer position even if you did get a mountain double crank that also had an outer chainring size that worked well with it. It certainly won't work with the chainline needs of the bike in boost mode, although Fargo and other Alternator dropout bikes can have 142x12 or 135 QR dropouts swapped in to solve that (untrue of most Boost bikes). The problem with contriving to make your GRX front derailleur work on it is that Boost is a good thing for everything that frame is trying to do, so jumping through a bunch of hoops just to get rid of the Boost-ness is a waste. (You also don't mention whether you already have Boost wheels for the bike).

I would consider using the left STI to control a dropper (or sell it and get an BL-RX810 and no dropper) and then 1x'ing the bike like [this](https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/#VII), using a Wolf Tooth Goat Link to hack the B-knuckle of your RD-RX812 so you can run an 11-50. Bikes set up this way work well and it's far less of a hack setup than anything that has you shifting a mountain double crank with an STI.

Edit: Weiwen Ng points out that even in Boost configuration, the frame can't clear greater than a 42t chainring. That means there's no reasonable way to use a road/gravel FD with it.

Comment: May be worth adding: the Fargo specs say 42t max chainring for a double, 36t for a Boost 1x, 34t for a nonBoost 1x. Unfortunately, this is one time where reading the manual before buying components would have really saved a lot of trouble https://www.salsacycles.com/bikes/2021_fargo_apex_1

Answer (score 3):

A 5 months update:

After this question has been asked (and answered), SRAM has released a few gravel products that can fit 73mm BB shells. They are called "wide". At the time of writing of this answer, there are 4 models:

- Two single chainring 40T (in Rival and Force ranges)
- Two double chainring 43/30T (in Rival and Force ranges)

These are 12-speed. If my understanding of the SRAM range is correct, the single chainring crankset can be paired with a 10-44 XPLR cassette or a 10/51 Eagle cassette (with a GX derailleur then), and the double with 10-36. And in 12 speed/road, SRAM only offers electronic transmission, so the whole drivetrain and brakes will need to be replaced. Not a cheap operation, but a step in the right direction for those who are looking to fit larger chainrings than 36T on 73mm BB.

Although the single chainring may probably be used with other brands/combinations.